# String concatenation to reference a srting variable in Python

Tags: python, string, variables

new at this so probably the first of a series of silly questions ...

Basically I am looking to see how (or if possible) to concatenate a string (say) "row" with a numeric variable (say) i = 1 to get "row1" and use THAT to reference a string called "row1"

Basically if I had a series of rows:

```
row1 = "12345"
row2 = "ABCDEFG"
row3 = "98765"
```

etc`

I was looking for data in a row defined by nested loops that returned i = 2 and j = 3 meaning
I wanted to get the 3rd index of row2 (i.e. pseudocode row(i)[j]), basically row2[3] returning "D".

I can concatenate the strings ok to get a new string "row2" but can't quite crack how to use that as a base for the [3].  I fully appreciate there are better ways of manipulating the data with dictionaries etc but, to advance my understanding, I am just playing about with strings at the moment and this 'feels' like it should be possible.

Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: `row[i][j]` works fine if `row = [row1, row2, row3]`. Is that what you want? (Note that i = 2 will give you row3, not row2.)

Comment: The way to access multiple values, distinguished by a number, is to put them into a *list*, and use indexing.  (Or possibly a dictionary, if the numbers aren't consecutive.)

Comment: Alternatively: `row = {1: row1, 2: row2, 3: row3}` could work, but is less standard idiom, in particular if the outer indices (`i`) are consecutive.

Comment: I feel a bit dim now because I should have spotted  row[i][j] = [row1, row2, row3 etc] as it makes perfect sense.  I already that the [row1, row2 etc] but was only using to iterate over rows vertically ... my brain just took them as mere strings rather than the collection of arrays that they individually are!

Comment: sorry, how do i mark this as answered/give reputation?  Cant find the "green tick" :-)

Comment: You can only "green tick" answers, not comments on stack overflow.